# HDFS: параллельная запись в каталог?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Принцип **write-once-read-many**,на котором построена HDFS,не позволяет нескольким процессам/клиентам одновременно писать в один файл. А как насчет каталога? Могут несколько процессов одновременно создавать и писать в файлы в одном каталоге?
Не смог найти в документации ответ на этот вопрос (может и плохо искал,не спорю).
Могу,конечно,накидать тестовый пример параллельной записи для проверки,но вдруг есть готовый ответ?

Answer (score 0):

Хм,раз никто не ответил,пришлось проверять практически. Да,параллельно писать в каталог можно. Нижеприведенный код корректно отрабатывает.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;

public class ParallelDirectoryWrite extends Configured implements Tool{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
         int res = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new ParallelDirectoryWrite(), args);
         System.exit(res);
    }

    @Override
    public int run(String[] args){


     try {

        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        Configuration conf = this.getConf();

        Thread th1 = new Thread(new FileWriteThread(conf,new Path("/ptest/fileA"),512,latch));
        Thread th2 = new Thread(new FileWriteThread(conf,new Path("/ptest/fileB"),512,latch));

        th1.start();
        th2.start();

        System.out.println("Launching threads...");
        latch.countDown();

        th1.join();
        th2.join();

        System.out.println("Main thread finished");

        return 0;

      }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return 1;
      }

    }

}

class FileWriteThread implements Runnable {

    private Configuration conf;
    private Path file;
    private int size;
    private CountDownLatch latch;
    private final int MEGABYTE=1_048_576;

    public void run() {

        try {

            latch.await();
            System.out.println("Writing "+file.getName()+" started at "+now());
            FileSystem fs  = FileSystem.get(conf);
            if(fs.exists(file))
                fs.delete(file, false);
            FSDataOutputStream out = fs.create(file);
            int total = size*MEGABYTE;
            for(int i=1;i<=total;i++) {
                out.writeByte((int)'y');
                if(i % MEGABYTE == 0)
                    out.hflush();
            }
            out.close();
            System.out.println("Writing "+file.getName()+" finished at "+now());

        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private String now() {
        return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(new Date());
    }

    public FileWriteThread(Configuration conf, Path file, int size, CountDownLatch latch) {
        this.conf = conf;
        this.file = file;
        this.size = size;
        this.latch = latch;
    }

}
```